# Count other table data and display in primary table in php laravel with select subquery

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables as category and product. I have to count similar data from table product and display count in table category. I am using this query in laravel to display category detail.

```
$data = CategoryModel::orderBy('id','ASC')->get();
```

In core php I used the following query to display counted data in table 1.

```sql
SELECT tbl_category.*,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_product
WHERE tbl_product.v_category = tbl_category.v_name) AS TOTAL FROM tbl_category
```

Now I want to implement above query in laravel. how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I need more details but I am assuming that a product is mapped to multiple categories so there would be a model file named Category mapped to table categories and there would be Product.php model file mapped to products table

Below snippet in your controlled would help

```
App\Product::withCount('categories')->get()
```

Please sure to have below in your Product.php (Model file)

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->hasMany('\App\Category');
}
```

Note the count of the categories associated with a product would be return as categories_count in the collection

Comment: i have two table category and product. In product table i inserted multiple category name like mobile, laptop, console category assigning to products now i want to count how many mobiles ,laptops and consoles in product table and display that count to category table

Comment: I would recommend one to many relationships here i.e. 1 category (say Mobile) can have multiple products assigned to it. Therefore, you need to create two models and two tables i,e. one for categories and one for products. Can you please share the sample data as row and columns. I can help you accordingly.